# Create a sequence number odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to create a sequence number odoo 10 (some think like OM-201709-001) I have use this code for:

***.xml**

```xml
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="seq_type_id" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">omega_sequence</field>
        <field name="code">hr.employee</field>
        </record>

        <record id="seq_id" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">omega_sequence</field>
        <field name="code">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="prefix">SQ</field>
        <field name="padding">5</field>
        <!--<field name="suffix">suffix</field>-->
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

and for :

***.py**

```py
class omega(models.Model):
    _name = 'omega.model'
    _description = 'No Description for now !!'

    sequence_id = fields.Char('Sequence', readonly=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('hr.employee') or '/'
        vals['sequence_id'] = seq
        return super(omega, self).create(vals)
```

but I get all time this error what ever I do :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 410, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 82, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 796, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 625, in _tag_record
    model = self.env[rec_model]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 760, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 174, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
ParseError: "ir.sequence.type" while parsing /home/walid/Bureau/model_x/views/Sequences.xml:3, near
<record id="seq_type_id" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">omega_sequence</field>
        <field name="code">hr.employee</field>
        </record>
```

I have search in all site web I have found, the are giving me the some code, but all time I execute this code he give me the error above; please give me an advice and thanks.

Comment: Is this for a custom module? If so, does your __openerp__.py file have a dependency with the base module?

Comment: are that what you asking for : 'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
        'views/*.xml',
    ],

Comment: yes, but there should be a different value to set.  'depends' : ['base'],
try updating that field, restart the openerp service, then install/upgrade the module

Comment: http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/docs/__openerp__.py.html

Answer (score 6):

`ir.sequence.type` model [has been removed](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/d6e9abd8b83b47a28efc46057d8c86df1eaf800a#diff-d5a9f36fcd57fde041ca35f40c99c80cL32) in version 9.0. You can use this code:

```xml
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">

        <!-- ------*.xml file------- -->
        <record id="seq_hr_employee" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">omega_sequencer</field>
            <field name="code">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="prefix">QO</field>
            <field name="padding">5</field>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

```py
# ------------*.py file------------------
class omega(models.Model):
    _name = 'omega.model'
    _description = 'No Description for now !!'

    sequence_id = fields.Char('Sequence', readonly=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('hr.employee') or '/'
        vals['sequence_id'] = seq
        return super(omega, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: that give me this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)[[[...]]]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3782, in <lambda>
    @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Add return super(omega, self).create(vals) in create methode i have edit the code